# Post to friend wall in facebook in iphone?

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I am trying to post on my friend wall by using its friend id like this

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"1581445658/feed"
                          andParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"hello very good morning" forKey:@"message"]
                      andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                        andDelegate:self];
```

but getting error 400 bad request. Please suggest me how to to get the rid of this bad request.

Note: This method work for first 10-15 time after that its start giving this error. Now it is continuously giving this error.

Comment: What actual error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your ID is blocked by FB. So you have tried with other ID ?

Comment: Is there is any number of wall post limit with Facebook. That we can post in one day or in a particular time. Because I didn't get this in Facebook documentation.

Comment: Yes, I think they have limit or your post is marked as spam so.. you are facing problem in this.

Comment: Is there is something related to verified non-verified Facebook Account.

Comment: Yes, If you account is verified in Mobile device then you are able to post more msgs on your frnd wall.

Comment: ok, But when it will be resumed...I have tried from my Fbacoount I can make wall post from there...